# Overriding a class in prestashop

Tags: php, overriding, prestashop, e-commerce, prestashop-1.6

I tried to create override for class`OrderCore`, located in `/classes/order/Order.php`. The result I put in `/override/classes/order/Order.php` with following content:

```
class Order extends OrderCore {
    /**
     * Generates reference number.
     *
     * Overriten to have reference numbers numeric only.
     */
    public static function generateReference()
    {
    return strtoupper(Tools::passwdGen(9, 'NUMERIC'));
    }
}
```

After doing this nothing happened. Additionally I tried following (with the same unsuccesful result):

- Delete cache using backoffice
- Delete manually `cache/cache_index.php`
- Disable overrides, delete cache in the BO and `cache/cache_index.php` and enable overrides afterwards

Can you tell me, where could be the catch? I'm using Prestashop v. 1.6.1.18.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So,

the problem was pretty basic (as the most of them are). I forgot to simply add `<?php` in the beginning of the file, so it wasn't recognised as a php class, but as a text.